# multiple projects jqassistant

Tags: eclipse, maven, jqassistant

I have multiple maven projects that are related to each other in Eclipse. 
Now I need to check the projects e.g. for cyclic dependencies. What I have is a folder that contains the constraints in every single project.

Is there a possibility to check the rules (constraints) with jqassistant without putting them into a folder in each project ? 
Maybe there is a way to define the rules in a root project and let the tool know which projects it has to search for.

thanks for help

Tino

PS: Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 2):

there's currently only one way to share rules between projects by creating a plugin, i.e. a JAR file containing rules.

The documentation provides examples for

1. The [structure](http://buschmais.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.0.0/#_custom_rule_plugin) of such a plugin
2. How a plugin is [used](http://buschmais.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.0.0/#_using_custom_plugins) with jQAssistant.

Would that solve your problem?